# How to apply a rule to factors matching a certain form

Tags: functions, replacement, rule

Suppose we have many expressions involving irrational `ArcTan` expressions (such as `ArcTan[Sqrt[3],5]`) along with other irrational factors (such as `1/Sqrt[2]`).

I want to simplify all of these `ArcTan`s. For example, I might want to apply `N` to them to get their decimal approximation, or I might want to apply `Rationalize` as in

```
N@ArcTan[Sqrt[3], 5]
(* out: 1.23732 *)   

Rationalize[ArcTan[Sqrt[3], 5]/Pi, .0001] Pi  
(* out: 13 Pi/33 *)
```

However, I would like to be able to implement either of these options throughout large expressions involving many `ArcTan` functions and not act on any other forms.

Simple example would be:

```
m = 1/Sqrt[3]+ Sqrt[2] ArcTan[Sqrt[3], 5]
```

How can I apply a rule or something to `m` that will allow me to implement one of these types of solutions to the `ArcTan` but not act on the other irrational factors?

Comment: Something like `m /. ArcTan[Times[x_, y_]] :> 
  ArcTan[fff[x], ggg[y]] /; ! Element[x | y, Rationals]` may work

Comment: It may, but I haven't yet been able to construct fff and ggg correctly to implement it this way.

Comment: For example `m = 1/Sqrt[3] + Sqrt[2] ArcTan[Sqrt[3], 5];
f[u_] := u /. ArcTan[Times[x_, y_]] :> (Rationalize[ArcTan[Times[x, y]]/Pi, .0001] Pi) /; ! Element[x | y, Rationals]; f[m]`

Answer (score 4):

Approaching (stealing) of [Dr. Belisarius's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/how-to-apply-an-rule-to-factors-matching-a-certain-form#comment131103_43903) answer which was very helpful, I present my answer:

Providing an `m` equation:

```
m = 1/Sqrt[3]+ Sqrt[2] ArcTan[Sqrt[3], 5]
```

> $\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{2} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{3}}\right)$

You can implement this type of solution:

```
f[u_] := u /. 
  ArcTan[x_ y_] :> π Rationalize[ArcTan[x y]/π, 0.0001];
f[m]
```

> $\frac{13 \pi  \sqrt{2}}{33}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$